# Alias column mapping in simple.data for DML

Tags: simple.data

Is there any one using Simple.Data ORM https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data. Any idea how to implement alias column names and table names for all the DML operation. I've referred http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/ . It talks about alias in Select query? I'm looking for something like config file which holds alias column/tables names

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Simple.Data doesn't have a mechanism for using the same aliases for columns and tables again and again. You have to use the As method to use aliases each time you make a query. So for column aliases, have a look at http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/ColumnAliasing.html and for table aliases for use in join queries, have a look at the section on Explicit Joins at http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/LazyLoadingJoins.htm

Comment: Thanks Hmobius for responding, I had look on the alias on select query, but im looking for dml operation like update/insert..